# Nodejs recursion call stack error, but the code should be just fine

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code errors in Node 12 and I want to know why?

```js
function nloop(i, func) {
  function recurse(obj, i, count) {
    obj[count += 1] = func.call(null, count);
    if (count === i) return obj;
    return recurse(obj, i, count);
  };
  return recurse([], i - 1, -1);
};

var data = nloop(1000000, i => Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000));
```

```
                          ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at /Users/j/dev/algos/perf/mergesort.perf.js:20:27
    at recurse (/Users/j/dev/algos/nloop.js:3:26)
    at recurse (/Users/j/dev/algos/nloop.js:5:12)
    at recurse (/Users/j/dev/algos/nloop.js:5:12)
    at recurse (/Users/j/dev/algos/nloop.js:5:12)
    at recurse (/Users/j/dev/algos/nloop.js:5:12)
    at recurse (/Users/j/dev/algos/nloop.js:5:12)
    at recurse (/Users/j/dev/algos/nloop.js:5:12)
    at recurse (/Users/j/dev/algos/nloop.js:5:12)
    at recurse (/Users/j/dev/algos/nloop.js:5:12)
```

I don't believe there to be an actual call stack error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code errors in Node 12 and I want to know why?

The maximum call stack size in Node 12 is less than 1,000,000, which is what your code would require in order to complete. I tested using 12.7.0 and i see a max stack size of 12,461

In principle, tail-call optimization should be able to make this code work, but node doesn't implement tail call optimization (source: https://node.green/#ES2015-optimisation-proper-tail-calls--tail-call-optimisation-)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to increase and and/or run recursion on big data?

Comment: Without tail call optimization, not really. But you could look into Trampolines (eg, https://blog.logrocket.com/using-trampolines-to-manage-large-recursive-loops-in-javascript-d8c9db095ae3/). You mentioned you were doing this for performance reasons; i suspect you'll have better performance if you do it with a loop than recursion + trampoline.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use dynamic programming to prevent this error. Instead of having recursive functions, use a loop and store each result in an array. Please take a look at this code:

```js
const i = () => Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000);
const data = (new Array(1000000)).fill(0).map(i);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I'm using recursion for perf.

Comment: @iamdevonbutler using recursion does not always result in performance.

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes I didn't notice `=` sign! and I think it's just `count+1`. Thanks